# How to add text and images in pdf using tcl script

Tags: pdf, tcl, pdflib

I am trying to add some content text as well as graphics to pdf using tcl script. Do you have idea about any library that has the suitable APIs for adding text and images to pdf using tcl script.

Thank you.

Comment: call a perl script to do the work...

Answer (score 0):

Try using this library:
http://pdf4tcl.sourceforge.net/

You can find documentation here: http://pdf4tcl.sourceforge.net/pdf4tcl.html

Also usefull link is TCL Wiki: [http://wiki.tcl.tk/_/search?S=pdf&*charset*=UTF-8](http://wiki.tcl.tk/_/search?S=pdf&_charset_=UTF-8)